# Django flash database object

Tags: django

I want to make an app where someone can search for something. When he searches he will get all of the things in the database that start with anything he wrote. I am using the messages framework.Here is the backend code:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']

        search = Team.objects.filter(name__startswith=name).all()
        if not search:
            messages.info(request, 'There wasnt')
        else:
            #looping all the items that search has
            for i in search:
                #flash the object
                messages.info(request,i)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

And the HTML code:

```
{%if messages%}
    {%for msg in messages%}
        <div class='searching'>
            #showing the name and the title of the object
            <p style='color:white;margin-left:25px;'>{{msg.name}} {{msg.title}}</p>
        </div>
    {%endfor%}
{%endif%}


<form action='' method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control"  type='text' name='name'>
        <br>
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>OK</button>
    </form>
```

But when I run it I don't get anything. Also I don't use `extra_tags` because  I want the `name` and the `title` appear in the same `div`.
What should I do?

Pls can someone reply? I really need a help. Plsss.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to pass the messages object to the html template. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-templates/#:~:text=The%20context%20object%20we%20sent%20from%20the%20view,template%20renders%20to%3A%20My%20first%20name%20is%20Naveen. this might help

Comment: But it sent the object with the ``i`` where I looped the search.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. You are ussing the messages framework I guess. You should mention that in your post to avoid confusion. Can you also include the html code of your post form and the view that renders your form?

Comment: okay i am gonna do